# How to Create and Format HTML table in Logic Apps

Tags: azure-logic-apps

How can we create html table with lines in Logic apps? Following is the table i have created using 'Create HTML table' action.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNSEk.png)

Getting data in table which doesnt have lines. how can i format html to get the table structure with horizontal and vertical lines?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzR1f.png)

Comment: May I know where are you going to show this table ? In email ?

Comment: Yes , in outlook Email

Comment: Hi Maruthi, please refer to the solution I provided below.

Answer (score 1):

As "Create HTML table" action can not show horizontal and vertical lines, so we can add style when we send the table in email. Please refer to the screenshot below(set "Is HTML" field to "Yes"):
[image]

After running the logic app, I received an email shown as below:
[image]

Comment: I dont see IsHTML option in my logic apps.Following is the screenshot for reference.

Comment: @MaruthiKiran Which connector did you choose to add the "Send an email" action? Office 365 Outlook ? or Outlook.com ? IsHTML option just exists in 'Send an email" action from "Outlook.com" connector.

Comment: Sorry,I couldnt upload the screenshot.

Comment: i have used Office 365 Outlook

Comment: Thanks a lot Shen.i will try out in Outlook connector.

Comment: I cant see an option as IsHTML in Office 365 > Send an Email (V2)

Comment: @hiFI IsHTML option just exists in Outlook.com connector but not Office 365 connector, I mentioned it in the comments above.